# Get Census Tract given a Census Block OR Get Census Tract given Latitude/Longitude

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, united-states, census

I'm using Python and am looking to get the Census Tract of a location given **either** a latitude and longitude **or** a census block. I can get the census block given latitude/longitude from here: https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/#!/block/get_block_find but I don't know how to go from census block to census tract.

I need census tract data because I'm working with the Social Vulnerability Index data which is census-tract level.

Comment: What is returned by the API? If it is the FIPS code for the block, then you can use that to get the tract, as blocks are nested within block groups (12 digit FIPS) and then nested within tracts (11 digit FIPS).

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

Following @smiller suggestion in the comments above, I plugged the example coordinates and year (38:15:36N and 77:30:36W for Census 2010) into the linked FCC API and got Block FIPS code 511770203042000, where state=51, county=117, tract=020304, block group=2, and block=000. See the Census [documentation](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/guidance/geo-identifiers.html) for more detail.

Make sure you are querying the right year, or you may get the wrong codes.